# How to check for conditional properties on the global window object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I need to check the window global for an `init_data` object that may or may not be there. Trying to access it directly Typescript complained: `Property 'init_data' does not exist on type 'Window'`

I had a working workaround but it no longer works with Typescript 2.4.

The workaround was:

```
interface Window {
  init_data?: any
}

const isLoggedIn = function() {
  let win:Window = window
  return win.init_data ? true : false
}
```

This now throws the error: `error TS2559: Type 'Window' has no properties in common with type 'Window'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const isLoggedIn = () => !!window['init_data'];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I don't understand why typescript doesn't complain though? Or why it was complaining in the first place?

Comment: When you use foo.bar, TypeScript checks that bar is indeed a declared property of foo. When you use foo['bar’], you're treating foo as a dictionary/map. It's the way you tell the TS compiler that bar is a dynamic property of foo. And it thus doesn't check if that property exists.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity~!